# How/best way to send a Form with multiple images as checkboxs

Tags: php, email, submit

I'm trying to create a page with 100 of images to choose from by checkboxs to be sent by email through php. Should I be using an array somehow?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/np5zqna8/

I copied all the code inside the fiddle.jshell besides the other images.

Comment: forgive the php code. I've only don'e php for emails

Comment: I've gotten a little further digging further into my research

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/0bxz2Lou/

Comment: It is sending the correct information over but it's not allowing multiple items. It only sends one.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use a lib like Swiftmailer and attach you images.

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

On the site is an example how to attach some files. Swiftmailer do the rest for you. And i hope i understood you problem correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry I should of put more time/information in my Question. I have a page already using Wordpress. The Current Code I have posted in the Fiddle is working atm but it's only for two images right now and it's not presented neat in the email. I'm looking for a better way to send the checked images in a more Presentable Email. The Current Problem I'm running into is I dunno what values I should pass or if I should use an array. Simply all I'm wanting in the email is User Chose Image One, User Chose Image 14 and So on.

Answer (score 0):

I gave an array to the name value of the checkboxs